# Typescript generic of union type: find out type of property from other property

Tags: typescript, generics, union-types

I have a union type with `payload` and `type` properties, from which `type` us uniq. I would like to infer the payload type when given the `type`.

```js
type AAction = {type: 'A', payload: APayload};
type BAction = {type: 'B', payload: BPayload};

type APayload = number;
type BPayload = string;

type Actions = AAction | BAction;

const actions: Actions[] = [];

type PayloadOfType<T extends Actions['type']> = ????

type PayloadOfTypeA = PayloadOfType<'A'>;
```

so the goal is that `PayloadOfTypeA` would be equal to `APayload` (or `number`).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional type `Extract`:

```
type AAction = {type: 'A', payload: APayload};
type BAction = {type: 'B', payload: BPayload};

type APayload = number;
type BPayload = string;

type Actions = AAction | BAction;

const actions: Actions[] = [];

type PayloadOfType<T extends Actions['type']> = Extract<Actions, { type: T }>['payload']

type PayloadOfTypeA = PayloadOfType<'A'>;
```